# Creating parser with percentiles:'0,50,90,100,' filterRegex:null Cannot detect file type because of error: Failed to copy jmeter-newtest.csv

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, jmeter-maven-plugin

Build is failing in execute jmeter stage, I'm attaching both error and jmeter build stage below

could some hlep me in this

**Jenkins pipelnie :**

```
stage('Execute Jmeter') {
              when {
              expression { return pipelineStages.contains("JMETER-TEst") }
          }
        steps{
            sh 'pwd'
}
        post{
           always{
             dir("/target/jmeter/results/"){
                 sh 'pwd'
                 perfReport 'jmeter-newtest.csv'
            }
         }
       }     
    }
```

**Error :**

```
Creating parser with percentiles:'0,50,90,100,' filterRegex:null

Cannot detect file type because of error: Failed to copy /target/jmeter/results/jmeter-newtest.csv to /data/jenkins/jobs/project-service/branches/adding-jmeter-build-step/builds/19/temp/jmeter-newtest.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have `/target/jmeter/results/`, it looks like an [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) and I believe you need the **relative** path to the [Jenkins workspace folder](https://jenkins-le-guide-complet.github.io/html/sec-hudson-home-directory-contents.html)

So my expectation is that if you change `/target/jmeter/results/` to `target/jmeter/results/` your script should start working as expected.

I also don't think you need to change the working directory, Performance Plugin can scan for result file(s) using [Fileset syntax](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) so you can just do something like:

```
perfReport '**/*jmeter-newtest.csv'
```

More information: [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin)